# MemoryStream to SecureString: Wiping the memory

Tags: c#

I am retrieving an `unencrypted` key from a `MemoryStream`, converting it to some kind of string, and using that string with .Net's `crypto` functions to encrypt data.  I need to make sure the `unencrypted` key is wiped from memory after using it.  I found `SecureString`, which I think will take care of the string, but I'm not sure how to wipe the memory of the key before it becomes a `SecureString`.

So the way everything works is:

> MemoryStream -> char[] -> SecureString

`SecureString` is passed the pointer to the char array, so it wipes the char array when it is finished? This is it's constructor:

```
SecureString(Char*,int32)
```

There is an example implementing it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/176bafkd(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, once the `SecureString` wipes the data (if it wipes the data), I still need to know how to wipe the data in the `MemoryStream`, and any intermediate objects I have to create in order to get the `char[]`.

So this question boils down to two parts:

How does one read a `MemoryStream` straight into a `char[]` without producing anything else in memory? (And if that isn't possible, what is the ideal transition? ie, `MemoryStream -> string -> char[]`?)

and,

How does one overwrite the memory used by the `MemoryStream` (and any other signatures created in the `MemStream->char[]` process) when finished?

Comment: What do you mean by _without producing anything else in memory_? When you read your stream, your key is _already_ in memory - presumably unencrypted. You can read that into a local `char[]` and pass to `SecureString`. Overwrite & delete the array once you're done. Is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: [Edited question to account for this] Yeah, I was thinking that as well.  I was trying to avoid overwriting anything in memory manually (because I have no idea how to do that).  So if I have the memory stream, read it into a char[], use secure string (which wipes the char array, right?) then I need to wipe the memory from the memoryStream...right?  How would I do that?  Is anything else created?

Comment: The short answer is you can't.  As soon as you've got the data in a regular managed string, you've already lost, and there's no real reliable way to get rid of it.

Comment: What about a seperate appdomain then?

Comment: @Servy Yes, there is, using a `char*` to overwrite the managed string's contents.

Comment: @xxbbcc The moment you stick it into a string it's possible for a GC to happen, resulting in the managed string to be copied from one location in memory to another.  At that point in time you'd be overwriting the value of the current string, but not the previous value that it was copied from.

Comment: @Servy You're right, there's no _absolute_ guarantee. And along the way the string may have been copied over a number of times. It'd be interesting to grab a full dump and search for the key just after setting up the `SecureString`.

Comment: oh man...so there is just no way?

Comment: @bordeo It's always possible for the value to be out there in the open.  You can make it *less likely*, but the instant you've stuffed the data into managed memory there's no way you can be sure it's not out there somewhere.

Comment: I would not use a string class for the variable.  Instead use a char[].  Then write over the array 5 times using an alternate pattern like {'0','0','0'} then {'1','1',1'}.  This isn't going to guarantee that a hacker will not be able to get the key, but it is the best you can achieve.

Comment: @Servy That's nuts.  So, basically, as you walk to the front of the house with the key, copies spill out all over the front lawn...Lol, we are supposed to secure this stuff.

Comment: @bordeo That's not at all like that. The "lawn" in this case is like the size of Texas with maybe 50 copies of the key scattered randomly around that slowly fade out over time. Sure, you can find a copy but, unless you know what it's for - it's not useful. Plus you can implement an unmanaged component that gets it into memory in a controlled way (for most of the way) - that significantly reduces the risk. (Still doesn't eliminate it _completely_.)

Comment: @jdweng I worked at a Dod lab once, and lost control of my mouse--someone was able to start using my ram through an exploit in Adobe Flash. These hackers know what's up...

Comment: @xxbbcc  lol, ok.. fair enough

Comment: @bordeo The point here is that you shouldn't be storing information in memory that you don't want the user executing the program to be able to access.  Don't be holding onto unencrypted sensitive data in memory if you don't want the admin of the machine running the code to access it.  If there's something sensitive that you want to do, and you want to ensure that your users can't ever access the data you're using, then you need to make a request out to a server/machine you own, do the work there, and then send a result back to them.

Comment: @Servy its server side getting an unencrypted copy of a key from Amazon Web Services alongside an encrypted version. We encrypt the key after using it to encrypt the data, and decrypt with a subsequent call to AWS.  AWS said to "simply overwrite the key in memory"...guess it isn't simple...but some minimum will have to suffice for HIPAA compliance, even though no user would ever have access to the data through normal use...

Comment: @bordeo You _can_ overwrite the _known_  (to you) instances of the key in memory - use `char*` to access the buffers of managed strings and overwrite them. Just be careful not to corrupt memory. You can't delete copies unknown to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `SecureString` doesn't wipe the memory of the input `char*` - you're responsible for that. It will only clean up its own internal storage.

To read/clean the contents of the `MemoryStream` into a local `char[]`, you can simply allocate the array (assuming that your stream contains a valid string):

```
// Get the contents of the stream.
var byKey = oMS.GetBuffer ();

fixed ( byte *pBytes = byKey )
{
    var oSecStr = new SecureString ( (char*) pBytes, 
        (int) ( oMS.Length / 2 ) );

    // Clear stream (there's no separate char/byte array
    // to clean).
    Array.Clear ( byKey, 0, byKey.Length );
}
```

This all, of course, assumes `unsafe` code. There's, however, no fully guaranteed way to clear all potential instances of the key from memory - during the calls to get the key into the stream, it may be copied a number of times (in various private buffers you have no access to) so you probably won't even know the number of copies lingering around.

Comment: You should use MemorySteams GetBuffer instead of ToArray though. It avoids creating a Copy of the internal Buffer of MemoryStream

Comment: ToArray will make an additional copy, GetBuffer won't. Also, you are truncating the last byte if length is not even.

Comment: @Zotta `Length` must be even if the stream contains a valid UTF-16 string. The OP will have to do his/her homework for error checking. :)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is more problematic than you might think. A MemoryStream is most likely used by something else and most likely grows in size over time.

Every time it grows, the data is copied into a new array internally and the old one is freed => your key could leak here

Also, a MemoryStream is most likely used by some other API. The other APIs will most likely not securely delete the key, because they are not designed to do so.

But to answer your original question: If the key is just ascii characters, you can just copy the bytes into a char array and overwrite the original bytes with random junk. You can acces its contents directly using `GetBuffer`.